# JAVAFX editable ComboBox: refresh after changing a value

Tags: combobox, javafx, converters, edit

I'm still new to JavaFX and need to create a combobox with objects (SimlpePerson) and not strings. I want to edit the shown value in the box itself. Works good for strings but I have problems with SimpleObjects. I made a StringConverter and it also works, I can edit the object shown in the comboBox. But the list itself is not rerendered after that. If I click on the ComboBox I see the original values. How can I change that?

Any suggestion is very welcome!=)

BR and Thank you!
Stefan

```
    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
    import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
    import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
    import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
    import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;
    import javafx.util.StringConverter;

    public class ComboBoxDemo extends Application{

      public class SimplePerson {
        private StringProperty name;
        private String somethingElse;

        public SimplePerson(String name) {
          setName(name);
        }

        public final void setName(String value) { nameProperty().set(value); }
        public String getName() { return nameProperty().get(); }

        public StringProperty nameProperty() {
          if (name == null) name = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "name");
          return name;
        }
      }

      final ObservableList<SimplePerson> persons = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            new SimplePerson("Jacob"),
            new SimplePerson("Isabella"),
            new SimplePerson("Ethan"),
            new SimplePerson("Emma"),
            new SimplePerson("Michael")
          );

      @Override
      public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        final ComboBox cb = new ComboBox();
        cb.setItems(persons);
        cb.setEditable(true);
        cb.setConverter(new StringConverter<SimplePerson>() {

          @Override
          public String toString(SimplePerson p) 
          {
            if(p != null)
              return p.getName();
            return "";
          }

          @Override
          public SimplePerson fromString(String name) 
          {
            if(cb.getValue() != null)
            {
              ((SimplePerson)cb.getValue()).setName(name);
              cb.show();
              return (SimplePerson)cb.getValue();
            }
            return null;
          }
        });

        stage.setScene(new Scene(cb));
        stage.show();

      }

      public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [this solution](http://pastebin.com/pNK6piez). There is a handler which is triggered when you've finished editing. There you may implement all the code which changes the model's state.

To update the combobox list the following approach work may:

```
 cb.getEditor().setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            SimplePerson person = cb.getValue();
            if (null != person) {
                int idx = persons.indexOf(person);
                person.setName(cb.getEditor().getText());
                persons.set(idx, person);
                cb.setValue(person);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hello Xuesheng, thank you for your contribution. I added that handler in JAVA 7 style. Works better now but still not allways. Please try the code, select "Emma" and change it to "Emma 123". Confirm it with Enter. If you open then the combo you can see "Emma 123" in the list. Repeat it with Isabella. You will still see "Isabella" and not "Isabella 123" in the combo box list